# What unit is used for the kern in NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

According to the [NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html):

> #### NSKernAttributeName
>
> The value of this attribute is an NSNumber object containing a floating-point value. This value specifies the number of points by which to adjust kern-pair characters.

When the document says "This value specifies the number of points..." is the term "points" referring to the screen points or something specific to font being used?

Comment: It also says that... _Kerning prevents unwanted space from occurring between specific characters and_ **depends on the font**. So here you go.

Comment: This is a really great question and deserves a "please update the documentation" request (the Provide Feedback link in the docs). It's not immediately obvious whether this is in screen points or in typography points (1/72"). My base assumption would be that it's in typography points, but I haven't tested this out.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a "point" is an arbitrary entity. On an iPad Mini, a point is 1 pixel wide and tall. On a 3rd/4th gen iPad, it's 2x2 pixels. It's a floating point value so that you can specify 0.5f points as your kerning value if you really want just one pixel's width of kerning on a retina display.